# Nickname vs. Alias in Google API

Tags: google-api, google-directory-api, google-provisioning-api

I am working on migrating some code that uses the Google APIs to manage users in my company's Google Apps domain before the April 20, 2015 deadline (see [Reminder to migrate to updated Google Data APIs](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2014/12/reminder-to-migrate-to-updated-google.html)).

I am new to this project and I am having trouble understanding nicknames, user aliases, and e-mail aliases.

1. In the "old" Google API environment (Provisioning API) what is the difference between a *nickname* and a *user alias*?
2. How do nicknames and user aliases in the old environment map to user aliases in the Directory API?
3. Where did nicknames go in the Directory API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They removed nicknames from Google Apps APIs.  Now they just call them aliases.  Here's the link - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/aliases

Answer (score 1):

You are only dealing with naming issues here. Email aliases used to be described as nicknames in Google Apps. You should migrate any nickname code you have to use the Alias API calls of the Directory API.